# jquery slider continuous slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a slider fiddle using jquery from another stackoverflow question

http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/2506/

```
target = $('ul.triggers li.selected').index();
target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
sliderResponse(target);
```

All I want to get is to turn this slider to continuous slider without getting back to the first item after it ends

I hope someone could explain to me how to do this with cloning because I don't understand this idea

ps no needs for any slider I need a code because I'm building a custom

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you want stop slider after last element you should add this row if (target != 0) after sliderResponse(target); call on line 40

Comment: Thank you . You didn't get my right what I mean I don't want to actually stop the slider I want the slider to keep slide after the last item with the first element directly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems you mean infinite scroller. I tried very quickly and made it

http://jsfiddle.net/samirkumardas/yznfmLs9/5/

Few things:

1. For infinite scroller, it is better to use a global variable for maintaining `current` slide number. For the simplicity I have used `auto_target` instead of your variable `target`.
2. The approach is to duplicate the first 1 or 2 slides (depends on mask width) and append these to the end of the slider container (append to UL)
3. When slider reach at the last slide, move slider to the duplicate slide(s) and pretends (highlight quick navigation I mean) that slider is at the position 0 (Since duplicate sliders are same as First slide(s))
4. When `current` slider number is greater than total number of slides(LI), set slider(UL) `left` position to 0 and set `target` slider to 1 because we have already shown first slider using duplicate

Hope it will help.

```js
var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
var images = $('ul.images li');
var lastElem = triggers.length - 1;
var mask = $('.mask ul.images');
var imgWidth = images.width();
var target = 0;
var auto_target = 0;
var mask_width = 340;
var slids_at_a_time = Math.ceil(mask_width / imgWidth);

triggers.first().addClass('selected');
mask.css('width', imgWidth * (lastElem + 1 + slids_at_a_time) + 'px');

function sliderResponse(target) {
  mask.stop(true, false).animate({
    'left': '-' + imgWidth * target + 'px'
  }, 300);
  triggers.removeClass('selected').eq(target % images.size()).addClass('selected');
}

triggers.click(function() {
  alert('not impletement');
});
$('.next').click(function() {
   alert('not impletement');
});
$('.prev').click(function() {
  alert('not impletement');
});

function sliderTiming() {
  auto_target++;
  if (auto_target > images.size()) {
    auto_target = 1;
    mask.css('left', 0);
  }

  sliderResponse(auto_target);
}
images.slice(0, slids_at_a_time).clone().appendTo(mask).addClass('duplicate');
var timingRun = setInterval(function() {
  sliderTiming();
}, 5000);

function resetTiming() {
  clearInterval(timingRun);
  timingRun = setInterval(function() {
    sliderTiming();
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
}
.mask {
  float: left;
  margin: 40px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 266px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.images {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
ul.images li {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
}
ul.triggers {
  position: absolute;
  top: 310px;
  left: 80px;
}
ul.triggers li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
  font: bold 16px arial;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.triggers li.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: #000;
}
.control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 380px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prev {
  left: 120px;
}
.next {
  left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mask">
  <ul class="images">
    <li>
      <img width="170" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg/270px-The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img width="170" src="http://www.mallorcaweb.net/masm/Planetas/Jupiter.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img width="170" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/FullMoon2010.jpg/280px-FullMoon2010.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img width="170" src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/gif/sun-update-1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img width="170" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Neptune.jpg/240px-Neptune.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ul class="triggers">
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
<span class="control prev">Prev</span>

<span class="control next">Next</span>
```

Comment: Thank you . You've clarified somethings for me but unfortunately your fiddle doesn't work I hope you check it out because it doesn't make infinite scroller like you've said .

Comment: @user3687377 You will have to duplicate slides depending on the size of the mask. I have updated fiddle. It should better now

Comment: Thank you Samir. I was able to understand cloning part of it thank you .

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/2510/)** so that it still carries on playing so if you click on a slide it will carry on the slider but otherwise it won't loop.

The key code is the `sliderTiming()` function:

```
if (target < lastElem) {
    sliderResponse(++target);
}
```

This means that `sliderResponse` (which triggers the sliding) will only happen if the current slide is not the last one.

The `++target` means "add 1 to target and then use it in context" (in context it's being passed as a parameter).

Comment: Thank you for help this isn't what I need . What I need is a way to make a cool infinite loop scrolling Thank you for your help .

Comment: How can it be continuous without going back to the first item?